# Failed build of Python project in Travis CI with unclear message

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm learning "by doing" Python (and some libraries) with a small personal project.

I have been working with a Minimal Product Viable approach, then I'm negleting some best pratices about the file and directory organization.

Furthermore I use this occasion to learn *pytest* (I used to test with *unittest* library) and [Travis](http://travis-ci.org) for the continous integration.

I created a specific [branch](https://github.com/alepuzio/calculate-priority-activities/tree/fix-travis) to test and consolidate my configuration in travis file, but after some test I'm blocked.

With this configuration

```
language: python
#python version
python: 3.8.6 
#define dependencsy
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# put testing framework
script: pytest
# allowed only these branch
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - develop
  - join-travis
```

I receive this [error](https://travis-ci.org/github/alepuzio/calculate-priority-activities/jobs/740996700):

> tests/test_NumberDays.py:61:
>
> ---
>
> tests/numberdays.py:20: in **init**
>
> self.log = PersonalLogging() tests/personalLogging.py:11: in **init**
>
> logging.config.fileConfig("config-log.ini",
> disable_existing_loggers=False)
>
> /opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py:71: in fileConfig
>
> formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
> /opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py:104: in
>
> _create_formatters
>
> flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
>
> ---
>
> self = <configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x7f845ff8e0a0>, key =
> 'formatters'
>
> def **getitem**(self, key):
>
> if key != self.default_section and not self.has_section(key):
>
> raise KeyError(key) E           KeyError: 'formatters'
>
> /opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/configparser.py:960: KeyError
>
> _______________________ ERROR at setup of testRunningOK ________________________
>
> @pytest.fixture
>
> def temporalRange () :

I think the problem of **KeyError: 'formatters'**  is :

**logging.config.fileConfig("config-log.ini", disable_existing_loggers=False)**

I create a personal logging class (**PersonalLogging**) that incapsulate the standard **logging** class and the **ini config file** is in the same directory of the other classes (N.D. I know, It s horrible, in the future I will correct the structure of the project: guys, do not take my example or your Team Leader will fire you at work  ^__^).

Now I have two problems:

1. If my hypothesis is correct, how I an fix it and have a successfull build?
2. If my hypothesis is uncorrect, what are (1) the correct explenation and (2) the solution?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

For same cause that I don't remember, I changed the name of file and pushed without testing the project with *pytest* .

Then, Travis did'nt find the config file of logging.

In local, after running the project, I had the same error (*KeyError* in formatters): the problem is the unreadable file